# Hashing length for storing password

Tags: hash, password-management

Does larger hash size improve the security? Is it overkill to use a 512-bit hash?

If I stored only 256 bits of the PBKDF2-SHA512 derived key, is it less, equal or safer than 256 bits of PBKDF2-SHA256?

Is the hash size only used to avoid hash collision, or does it improve security?

Is it secure if I only stored part of the hash (say the first 128 bits) of SHA-256 or SHA-512?

Comment: No; it's underkill to use a simple 512-bit hash.

Comment: "Is it secure if I only stored part of the hash (say the first 128-bits) of SHA-256 or SHA-512?" - don't do this, you exponentially increase your chance of a collison (with some data, from 'practically impossible' to 'almost certain'.

Answer (score 12):

A larger output length makes it stronger, up to a certain point which is already reached, by a large margin, when you have a 128-bit output. Enlarging it any further does not change security.

**Details:** barring any structural weakness, the security of a hash function depends on its resistance to generic attacks (aka "luck": attacker tries random inputs until a match is found), and that resistance depends on the hash output size. For a hash function with an output of *n* bits, it takes effort *2<sup>n</sup>* for the attacker to find a preimage (i.e. some password, not necessarily the "real" one, which matches the output). Efforts beyond about *2<sup>80</sup>* are too far away into the technologically infeasible to be envisioned by an attacker. At 128 bits, you already have a *2<sup>48</sup>* margin, i.e. a factor of almost 300 thousands of billions over that which was already overly expensive. It would be like boasting about reimbursing the US national debt while not having more than 0.01$ in cash.

Larger output size also help against collisions; there again, the generic luck-based attacks have cost *2<sup>n/2</sup>* (and there you see why SHA-1 has a 160-bit output: to make the collision cost of *2<sup>80</sup>* unreachable). However, collisions are not an issue for password hashing. The ability to compute collisions does not give any advantage to the attacker. It so happens that collisions are *also* infeasible with usual hash functions, but if they were feasible it would not be that much a problem.

**The real weakness in password hashing** is not the *hashing*; it is the *password*. Or, more accurately, the human mind behind the password. Successful attacks on hashed password are attacks which try potential passwords, not attacks which work on the hash function structural weaknesses, if any. Mitigations include slow hashing and salting, which is what PBKDF2 does.

You can store only 80 bits or so of PBKDF2 output (and the salt); things will still be safe. (For purely aesthetic reasons, make it 128 bits: these computer people, they just love powers of two.)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, a 512-bit hash is overkill.  128 bits is plenty.

Keep in mind that the security of your system is only as strong as the weakest link.  The weakest link, in this case, is almost certainly the entropy of the user's password.  [Most users choose poor passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/6697/971) that are [readily guessable](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/8287/971).  Increasing the hash length does nothing to stop this attack.

For this reason, the most important thing is to use a password hashing scheme that is designed to slow down guessing attacks on users' passwords, such as [bcrypt](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4781/971), [PBKDF2](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/971), or scrypt.  [Choose a number of iterations that makes password hashing as slow as you can tolerate](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/3959/971).  Make sure to use a random salt, too.  Make sure to [use SSL to protect transmission of the passwords from the user to your site](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/7057/971); I recommend you [use SSL site-wide](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/258/971).  Elsewhere I've offered [other suggestions for how to improve the security of password-based authentication](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/3943/971).

There's lots of additional information on this site about securing password storage.  Try the search bar: it you should find all sorts of good tips and helpful advice.

Answer (score 1):

While the security of any two hashing schemes is functionally equivalent onces its over ~100-bits unless there's some major flaw -- I wouldn't say a 512-bit hash is **overkill**.  The length of a hash as long as its more than 128-bits is largely irrelevant.

Do you have enough passwords in your database that storing an extra (512 bits=64 bytes; 128 bits = 16 bytes) 48 bytes per user is significant?

Hell, many systems will store your hashes as ASCII hex-strings (meaning every byte takes two ASCII characters between `0-9a-f` to store), which so you can often optimize down the size of your hashes by going to a binary blob if you want.  However, you rarely don't care about saving dozens of bytes on a modern system.  If you have a million users its still only an extra 48 MB, which is still trivial to throw hardware at.  And we recommend using slow hashes (e.g., bcrypt/scrypt), the performance issues of fetching/comparing the hash are irrelevant (in fact larger hashes are slightly better in this respect as they'll be slightly slower).

I use SHA-512 crypt on my linux systems.  (This is not a simple sha-512 hash; but by essentially 5000 (default) rounds of [SHA-512](ftp://ftp.arlut.utexas.edu/pub/java_hashes/SHA-crypt.txt).)  I don't use this because I need more than SHA-256 crypt, but it was the default with my distro (and the extra 43 bytes per user is completely irrelevant (its in a base64-like encoding)).  It has the added small benefit if a future attack on SHA is ever found that reduces its complexity significantly, I started from a much safer starting location.  (E.g., if you find a pre-image attack that makes it simpler by a factor of 2<sup>64</sup>, 128-bit hashes are compromised while 256/512-bit hashes would be fine).

Answer (score 0):

The number of bits used for storing a user's password hash will determine the maximum number of significant characters in a user's original unhashed password. Any characters beyond that limit that the user puts in their password will not add to the security of the password. Thus having more bits in your users' password hashes will increase the maximum possible security level of their passwords.

The minimum security level is determined by the strength of the user's original unhashed password. If weak passwords are used then having extra bits for the user's hashed password will mean nothing. The reason is that the most effective attack against hashed passwords is a dictionary attack. The effectiveness of a dictionary attack is determined by the strength of the users' unhashed passwords.

Quantitatively 512 bits can represent 77 characters of the typical 95 ASCII easily typeable characters commonly used in passwords. This is an overkill since most users will not be able to remember passwords that long.

512 bit password hash = 2<sup>512</sup> ≈ 1.34E+154 unique values

77 password characters = 95<sup>77</sup> ≈ 1.93E+152 unique values

78 password characters = 95<sup>78</sup> ≈ 1.83E+154 unique values

Answer (score 0):

There are [94 "printable" ASCII characters](http://facweb.cs.depaul.edu/sjost/it212/documents/ascii-pr.htm) (since the DEL character doesn't count), so your password hash would presumably need to be at least `ceiling(L*lg(94))` bits long to retain all of the entropy from the shortest passwords you can permit (that is, given a *[minimum password length requirement](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47098/where-did-common-minimum-password-length-guidelines-originate)* of `L`).

So, for example, a 64-bit password hash would only support random ASCII passwords up to 9 characters long. While this may seem fine (considering that the average password entropy [may be much less](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/54863/25009) anyway!), I would still second [Thomas Pornin's 128-bit suggestion](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/30663/25009) to not *alienate* those users who *actually* generate strong passwords beyond 64-bits of entropy (e.g, via a simple call to `openssl rand -base64 <num-bytes>`, or even those [built-in strong password generators](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-generate-secure-password-firefox) inside [common browsers](https://forbes.com/sites/brookecrothers/2021/02/07/google-chrome-has-a-strong-password-generator-how-to-avoid-password-hell/) as well!) by supporting random ASCII passwords even up to *19 characters* as well!